# How to cache dstream in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I want to read structed streaming data from kafka as dstream, and for each data, i want to handle it with many functions, so i try to cache the dstream.

```
lines = spark\
    .readStream\
    .format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)\
    .option(subscribeType, topics)\
    .load()\
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
lines.cache()
...
...
lines.cache()
```

however, i got the mistake as follow

```
Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to queue function. Just add lines.start() in the end.

Plz refer example code before asking question. 
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/sql/streaming/structured_kafka_wordcount.py

Comment: hi okwap, I know it is usefull in spark streaming ,however, i'm using spark structed streamming. Is it possible to add cache in structed streaming?

Comment: Is there any problem with lines.cache()?